# Looping through a Snowflake with PHP (Discord.php)

Tags: php, arrays, discord, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is my first post, I do a lot of reading here, so hopefully I avoid embarrassing myself. I've done a lot of searching on the topic, with little results, given that I am new to `PHP` it doesn't help either, and documentation is sparse on the topic.

The Discord API for `PHP` is limited to certain pieces of data which you can request, **what I am attempting to do is:** fetch the members, check what roles they have, and if they have it, count them.

Currently with the API you can count all members within a guild, however you cannot count all members within a guild with a specific role. My end conclusion is to loop through the snowflake and handle the comparisons myself.

This code returns the snowflake (up to 1000) for a guild:

```
<?php
    $json_options = [
      "http" => [
        "method" => "GET",
        "header" => "Authorization: Bot TOKENREDACTED"
      ]
    ];    
    $json_context = stream_context_create($json_options); 
    $json_get     = file_get_contents('https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/GUILDIDREDACTED/members?limit=1000', false, $json_context);
    $json_decode  = json_decode($json_get, true);
    print_r($json_decode);
?>
```

And the snowflake I am trying to loop through looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nick] => nickname
            [user] => Array
                (
                    [username] => username
                    [discriminator] => 7697
                    [id] => 123456789012345
                    [avatar] => 32ad726b873445fff9145e47144a9465
                )
            [roles] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 123456789012345678
                    [1] => 123456789012345678
                )
            [mute] => 
            [deaf] => 
            [joined_at] => 2018-05-18T07:22:49.562000+00:00
        )
    [1] => Array (annnd repeat for the next member)
```

As you can see the snowflake is quite complicated in terms of arrays.

What I am trying to do here is loop through each array entry (`[0]`,`[1]`,`[2]` etc.) then to the roles. If the `[user]` has the role ID `123456789012345678` (for example) then add that member to a count to print, if there's no match then it'll simply ignore that and move onto the next one. But I'm not really sure where to start with this. Any help or direction is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Start with `foreach ($json_decode as $member) { ... }` and you'll find the role IDs in `$member['roles']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array-filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and get only the element you need with [in-array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) and then count them using simple `count` method. Consider the following:

```
$arr = array_filter($json_decode, function($e) {return in_array("123456789012345678", $e['roles']);});
echo count($arr);
```

If the your "RoleId" is dynamic you can do:

```
$myRole = "123456789012345678";
$arr = array_filter($json_decode, function($e) use ($myRole) {return in_array($myRole, $e['roles']);});
```

If you also want to display the `username` you can do:

```
foreach($arr as $e) {echo $e['user']['username'];}
```

Comment: I am also going to try this out, thank you for the response. I'd be happy to mark this as the answer once I tailor this to my usage case. Regardless I think this information you've posted will be useful to anyone else reading this later on.

Comment: Your solution is shorter and more robust, so I am going to mark this as the answer, as it did work. Thank you!

Comment: Hey dWinder I actually have a followup question on this. Would there be a way to display the usernames of those who also have those roles? I'm also trying to add this to my website, however the issue I'm running into is comparing the [username] and [roles] keys. P.S. not asking for a spoonfeed here, just asking for some direction on getting other objects within a successful match.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably really, really bad practice, especially for a first post. @wesley murch thank you very much for the direction, I got it now. Also, feel free to reply so I can mark you as the answer. Here is the working code which I would like to share with everyone, and a following explanation of what the code does:

```
<?php
$json_options = [
  "http" => [
    "method" => "GET",
    "header" => "Authorization: Bot Your-Discord-Bot-Token-Here"
  ]
];

$json_context = stream_context_create($json_options);

$json_get     = file_get_contents('https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/your-guild-id-here/members?limit=1000', false, $json_context);


print_r(substr_count ( $json_get ,'Role-Id-To-Look-For'));
?>
```

This code will query the API for the snowflake, it then converts that snowflake to a string, and counts the occurrences of which that role is contained in the snowflake. In this case, I have 12 people with this role, I can confirm that it successfully returned a value of 12. In this usage case it wasn't necessarily a matter of parsing the array, I was able to just check the snowflake as a string for the ID I was looking for. This usage case is limited in the fact that it won't necessarily return any details of the members which have the role, so I wouldn't say it completely covers every single usage case.